# Finding a perpendicular to a plane

Tags: calculus, geometry, solution-verification

I saw this question:

> Calculate the length of the perpendicular from a point $P$ on the curve defined by $ax=y^2, by=z^2$
> to the $xz$-plane, where the perpendicular is also perpendicular to the plane defined by the tangent and subtangent to that curve.

I saw the following given as the solution.

$$ax=y^2,by=z^2$$
$$y=\sqrt{ax}$$
$$by=z^2\rightarrow b\left(\sqrt{ax}\right)=z^2$$
$$x=ay^2$$
$$z^2=by$$
$$z=\sqrt{by}$$
Define $$U=\left(x,y,z\right)$$
$$U=\left(ay^2,\sqrt{ax},\sqrt{by}\right)$$
$$\nabla U=\int\left(ay^2\right)dy+\int\left(\sqrt{ax}\right)dx+\int\left(\sqrt{by}\right)dz$$
$$\nabla U=a\frac{y^3}{3}+\sqrt a\frac{y^{-2}}{2}+\int\left(\sqrt{by}\right)dz$$
$$=a\frac{y^3}{3}+\sqrt a\frac{y^{-2}}{2}+C$$

Therefore, the length of $P$ is $\frac{ay^3}{3}+\frac{a^\frac{1}{2}y^{-2}}{2}+c$

I have a few questions: When it says $\nabla U=\int\left(ay^2\right)dy+\int\left(\sqrt{ax}\right)dx+\int\left(\sqrt{by}\right)dz$, why is the first integral with $dy$ and the second with $dx$?

Also, how did the third term become a constant?

Lastly, how did the results of $\int(\sqrt{ax})dx$ come about?

Is this answer correct? How can I solve my difficulties?

*EDIT:
Based on the comments I will include what I believe is the meaning of the subtangent:

Let P = (x, y) be a point on a given curve with A = (x, 0) its projection onto the x-axis. Draw the tangent to the curve at P and let T be the point where this line intersects the x-axis. Then TA is defined to be the subtangent at P. Similarly, if normal to the curve at P intersects the x-axis at N then AN is called the subnormal. In this context, the lengths PT and PN are called the tangent and normal, not to be confused with the tangent line and the normal line which are also called the tangent and normal. [image][image]

This is taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtangent)

Comment: What is the definition of subtangent?

Comment: @user Let P = (x, y) be a point on a given curve with A = (x, 0) its projection onto the x-axis. Draw the tangent to the curve at P and let T be the point where this line intersects the x-axis. Then TA is defined to be the subtangent at P. Similarly, if normal to the curve at P intersects the x-axis at N then AN is called the subnormal. In this context, the lengths PT and PN are called the tangent and normal, not to be confused with the tangent line and the normal line which are also called the tangent and normal.

Comment: If I understand correctly, we consider a 3d case here. So the tangent not necessarily intersects the $x$-axis, even if it is not parallel to it.

Comment: @user see edits made. Let me know if that is helpful.

Comment: No, it is not helpful. You consider two-dimensional case.

Comment: Besides in this definition subtagent is a length. And in your question it is certainly a line.